# Cannot reference child objects during this.props.list.map()

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am mapping over a this.props list and each element in the list has some child objects. However, if I try and reference any child objects, they are undefined.

Here is the loop

```
this.props.sparts.map((spart) => {
      sparts2.push(
          <div className="ui column wide spart-container" key="{spart.id}">
            <div className="fake-img"></div>
            <div className="audio-container">
              {spart.audio}
            </div>
            <div className="writing-container">
              {spart.name}
            </div>
          </div>
      )
    })
```

Example object:

```
{
  "name": "test name",
  "audio": {
    "name": "some name",
    "file_path": "some path"
  }
}
```

I can reference any immediate values fine (Like name) but if I try to reference spart.audio.name, it says Cannot read property name of undefined.

Why can't I reference child objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason I can think of would be that not every item in your array has an `audio` child. Therefor it is audio that is undefined and not the child of audio.

Use ternary operator to fix this

```
{spart.audio ? spart.audio.name : null}
```

Comment: Also your key looks strange. Im sure instead of
`key="{spart.id}"` you meant `key={spart.id}`

Comment: Oh my...thanks. I purposely  the data like that for testing too.

Comment: Also if `spart.audio` really is an object, you should not inject an object directly into a div. you have done so here
`<div className="audio-container">
              {spart.audio}
            </div>`

Comment: Well, I was planning on putting in one of the object values, not the entire object :)

Comment: Haha yes, sorry just being meticulous.